# ACL and Admin routing in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, acl

Let's begin by saying that my model classes are `User` and `Entries`.

I've read the following tutorial: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html and I see they use an extra model called `Group` in order assign a role to users.

1. What is different in using a `Group` model, instead of a `role` attribute in `User` (User.role = 'admin')
2. What is the difference in adding `Group` to the `ARO` instead of adding `User` to the `ARO`, and then using an alias.
3. If I implement ACL, does that means I no longer need admin routing?

**PD:** I am new to ACL list, I have always authorized actions using a something like `if($user['role'] == 'admin')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. These are two different ways of handling authentication. If you only have a few controllers and one or two admins, you'll probably be fine with using the `User.role` method you have now. If you have multiple controllers and various users who should have access to different sections of your site, you should use ACL.
2. You don't need to create `Groups` to use ACL, but it makes life a lot easier. Instead of assigning permissions for dozens of different users, you can create two or three groups, set the permissions for those groups, and then assign each user to one of the groups. Then, if you ever need to add a new controller -- or even a new view -- you only have to do that at the group level, instead of for each user. (Take a look at [this demo](http://demo.alaxos.ch/admin/acl/aros/role_permissions). Now imagine that you have another 10 controllers/50 actions and you have to set those permissions for 20 or 30 users instead of for 4 groups.) Of course, even if you are setting permissions at the `Group` level, you could always override them at the `User` level if you need to.
3. Admin routing is separate from ACL. Routing just controls the URLs you can use to get to pages. (See [Cake PHP - Prefix Routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing). You can use ACL control without admin routing, and you can use admin routing without ACL control.